# how to I process messages a set chunk at a time without losing messages that don't fit into a chunk

Tags: python, azure, message-queue, azure-queues

I need to process a set of messages and put them into chunks of 10 at a time. The total number of messages is unknown since they are feeding in as this process occurs.

simple example:

```
message_count = 0
chunk_limit = 10

while messages_exist:
     message_count += 1

     if message_count >= chunk_limit:
          process_chunk()
          print("chunk processed")
          message_count = 0
```

if I receive 14 messages, 4 will be left over because they are less than the chunk_limit. How do I make a chunk out of these leftover messages once I have processed 10 at a time?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, could you not just call process_chunk() after the while loop checking for messages is done? After the while loop exits, you know there are no more messages so you can just take whatever messages are left and have not been included in a chunk yet and make smaller chunk out of them.

May I know what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Firstly, recommend the to use the latest version of any of our libraries. In this case, it seems that the [azure-storage-queue](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-queue/) package is what are looking for (most updated version as of email: 12.5.0). Next, I would recommened towards our [sample code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/storage/azure-storage-queue/samples) as this is a great way to see some use-cases and  our package. Lastly, here is a code snippet you can be adjusted to fit your workflow.

```css
Code snippet:
from azure.storage.queue import QueueClient

# Your connection string (i.e. from Azure Portal --> Access keys)
CONNECTION_STRING = <your_connection_string_here>

# Your chunk limit (in this example, 10 messages per page)
CHUNK_LIMIT = 10

# Create queue from connection string and create queue object
queue = QueueClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=CONNECTION_STRING, queue_name="myqueue")
queue.create_queue()

# Saturate queue with 14 messages
for i in range(14):
    my_message = "Sending message #" + str(i)
    queue.send_message(my_message)

# Retrieve message in 2 chunks (up to 10 messages per chunk)
resp1 = queue.receive_messages(max_messages=CHUNK_LIMIT)
resp2 = queue.receive_messages(max_messages=CHUNK_LIMIT)

# Print contents to check (first will contain 10 messages, 2nd will contain 4 messages)
print("[Contents of chunk #1]")
for msg in resp1:
    print(msg.content)

print("[Contents of chunk #2]")
for msg in resp2:
    print(msg.content)

Sample output of above code snippet:
[Contents of chunk #1]
Sending message #0
Sending message #1
Sending message #2
Sending message #3
Sending message #4
Sending message #5
Sending message #6
Sending message #7
Sending message #8
Sending message #9
[Contents of chunk #2]
Sending message #10
Sending message #11
Sending message #12
Sending message #13
```